# ¿Tiniebla o Tinieblas?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, plurales

Yo sé que *tinieblas* significa oscuridad o algo semejante.

Mi pregunta es: ¿siempre se usa esa palabra en la forma plural? En mi diccionario también aparece *tiniebla*, pero nunca lo he escuchado de esa forma. ¿Hay un uso para *tiniebla* en la forma singular?

Y quizás una pregunta extra: ¿Por qué hay una palabra así que es plural pero que no significa algo que se puede contar? Yo sé de varias otras palabras que son plurales pero solo una cosa, por ejemplo:

> las tijeras

Pero esas palabras significan cosas de que se puede tener más que uno (una tijeras, dos tijeras). Pero no se puede contar *las tinieblas*. Es una sola cosa. Entonces, ¿por qué hay una forma plural?

Comment: El DRAE sólo menciona tiniebla, si bien es cierto que yo tampoco oí (ni leí) la palabra en singular.

Comment: La película traducida como "[En la tiniebla](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film832127.html)", ¿es un error? (Suena raro)

Comment: Y acá un libro: [Borges: la tiniebla y la gloria](https://books.google.cl/books/about/Borges_la_tiniebla_y_la_gloria.html?id=r9jBtoF7GS8C&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Último ejemplo, ya no molesto más. De Neruda, el soneto 57 termina así: "_y cuando me envolvió la claridad / nací de nuevo, dueño de mi propia tiniebla._" Buscando, la palabra aparece en singular, poco pero aparece, y creo que más que nada como recurso literario.

Comment: Let's ask the experts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-7EG1CaP58

Answer (score 3):

El DRAE [tiniebla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZnQw0J4) recoge 3 acepciones:

> 1. f. Falta de luz. U. m. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.
> 2. f. pl. Suma ignorancia y confusión, por falta de conocimientos.
> 3. f. pl. Oscuridad, falta de luz en lo abstracto o en lo moral.

De las 3 acepciones, sólo una es singular y se usa más en plural, por lo que no sorprende que "tiniebla" no se escuche en forma singular.

Answer (score 2):

Sobre tu pregunta extra, acerca de por qué se usa el plural en `tinieblas` cuando es algo que no se puede contar (no como, efectivamente, unas *tijeras*), lo único que puedo decirte es que se trata de un recurso literario que ha prevalecido hasta nuestros días. El idioma español tiende algo hacia la exageración (en algunas regiones más que en otras). La forma de hacer algo exagerado es diciendo que había mucha cantidad (había agua, había mucha agua), o directamente pluralizando aunque no se deba (las aguas del río). Posiblemente hayas visto también esto de *las aguas* en algunos textos. En Andalucía, por ejemplo, decimos que hay cuatro niveles de calor, de menor a mayor: *el calor*, *la calor*, *los calores* y *las calores*, a pesar de que el calor es algo que tampoco se puede contar (lo hacemos para exagerar).

Resumiendo: pluralizar algo que no se puede pluralizar es un recurso literario para indicar que había mucha cantidad o algo era muy grande o intenso. En el caso de `tinieblas` seguramente haya pasado que la forma plural suene mejor y la gente la haya adoptado por ello como la forma de uso común.

Comment: Interesante. Esto podría explicar "las escrituras" para referirse a la Biblia. Y "los cielos".

Comment: "Te he dicho cienes y cienes de veces ..."