# ¿Por qué estamos "en las últimas" y no "los últimos"?

Tags: género, locuciones

Cuando alguien va a morirse, suele decirse:

> Pobre Juan, **está en las últimas**: el cáncer se ha extendido tanto que ya no hay nada que hacer. Parece que morirá en breve.

La descripción es clara: está en los últimos momentos de su vida. Lo que me parece curioso es que se utilice la palabra en género femenino.

La RAE menciona distintas locuciones con último, ma:

> [**último, ma**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b2MGGOS)
>   Del lat. ultĭmus.
>
> (...)
>
> *a la última*
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. A la última moda.
>
> *a últimos, o a últimos de*
>   1. locs. advs. En los últimos días del período de tiempo que se indica o se sobrentiende. Estará aquí a últimos. Ven a últimos de semana.
>
> *estar alguien a lo último*
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. estar al cabo.
>
> *estar alguien a lo último de algo*
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. estar al cabo de algo.
>
> ***estar alguien a los últimos, en las últimas, o en los últimos***
>   1. locs. verbs. coloqs. estar al cabo.
>   2. locs. verbs. coloqs. Estar muy apurado de algo, especialmente de dinero.

Y la última es la que nos atañe aquí, donde ya se ve que se puede usar de distintas maneras: *a los últimos*, *en las últimas*, *en los últimos*. Todos son aceptados pero (al menos en España) solamente oigo *en las últimas*.

Sin ánimo de entrar en polémicas sobre el uso del masculino como genérico de la clase, ¿hay algún motivo para que se use el femenino aquí? ¿Será que hay alguna palabra femenina a continuación del *en las últimas* que se cayó por el camino?

<sub>Desde aquí mi sentido homenaje a Leonard Cohen, que sospechábamos que estaba en las últimas pero nos negábamos a creer que fuera cierto.</sub>

Comment: ¿En las últimas horas? (o instancias)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La palabra que buscas es, curiosamente, *palabras*:

> *Muriéndose un labrador, dijo **en las últimas palabras**:*
>
> *—Gracias a Dios que me ha quitado de esperar abril y mayo.*
>
> - Melchor de Santa Cruz de Dueñas, "Floresta española", España (1574)

Así pues, *estar en las últimas* haría alusión a las últimas palabras que pronuncia uno antes de fallecer. Otra opción es que la palabra que siga sea *agonías*, como acertadamente propone blonfu en [los comentarios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18758/por-qu%C3%A9-estamos-en-las-%C3%BAltimas-y-no-los-%C3%BAltimos/18759?noredirect=1#comment27718_18759):

> *Al jesuita Adamo Tannero, uno de los hombres más sabios de su tiempo, y no menos respetable por su virtud que por su doctrina, le sorprendió la última enfermedad, restituyéndose de la Universidad de Praga a su patria Inspruk, en un lugar corto. Quando ya **estaba en las últimas agonías**, la justicia registró sus ajuares para ponerlos en depósito.*
>
> - Benito Jerónimo Feijoo, "Theatro crítico universal, o discursos varios en todo género de materias, para desengaño de errores comunes", España (1728)

Una opción menos poética pero no menos cierta. La pluralización de *agonía* es similar a la de *tinieblas*, como vimos en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16706/12637). Los resultados del CORDE a partir del siglo XIX ya no usan ninguna palabra tras la expresión, y se limitan a "estar en las últimas".

Comment: Caramba, Carlos, ¡qué rapidez! Me gusta que sean _en las últimas... palabras_, le da un toque poético. Muchas gracias como siempre.

Comment: @fedorqui nada, aquí CORDE-man para lo que gustes.

Comment: @fedorqui la verdad es que esta expresión podría dar lugar a un debate filosófico. Si dices "en los últimos" puedes pensar que está en los últimos alientos, o instantes. En cambio aquí ha prevalecido "en las últimas", al parecer por la necesidad de comunicación del ser humano, una necesidad vital hasta el final, aunque no sepamos que la expresión viene de ahí.

Comment: Le veo incluso una connotación religiosa, como el de terminar la vida con un... "amén".

Comment: Me parece raro que se use el verbo estar si la palabra que se omite es _palabras_. Yo creía que eran las "últimas horas" pero no encuentro nada que lo corrobore así que supongo que no. En cualquier caso ¿Por qué _estar_?

Comment: @blonfu porque "estar en las últimas" se refiere a estar en un momento concreto de la vida, un momento que va a pasar. Es diferente a si dices "aquellas fueron sus últimas palabras", que entonces sí haces referencia a las palabras en sí. La expresión hace referencia al momento en que las pronuncias.

Comment: Vale, puede ser pero ¿cómo sabes que de ahí viene la expresión? ¿Por qué no de _las ultimas agonías_, por ejemplo? No es por tocar las narices, me interesa saber como estar seguro de donde viene porque una frase  que contenga "en las ultimas [algo]" es demasiado común

Comment: @blonfu y tienes toda la razón. Yo solo he puesto la primera referencia (la más antigua) que he encontrado en el CORDE. Simplemente me pareció plausible. "Agonía" no me pega porque es un sustantivo incontable, aunque se podría pluralizar para dar énfasis como pasa con "tinieblas", pero podría ser cualquier otra palabra. Aunque eso no varía el que se deba usar el verbo "estar" en la expresión.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, he puesto "agonías" porque he visto que se usa esa forma en varios textos y me encajaba. He entendido lo del verbo estar que se refiere al momento en que se dicen las palabras

Comment: @blonfu yo también acabo de encontrar referencias a esos textos, voy a ampliar la respuesta con tu propuesta.